# creating two grids one besides other each grid having each grid with two columns using dojo.

Tags: dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid, dojo

I want to have two grids one besides other. Each  one of this grid having each grid contains two columns. I need complete source code for this using DOJO.
Basically i am comparing data between two employees. So i can compare data between two employees.
I already created one grid which display one employee data but failed to create another grid beside this employee. I need help with displaying two grids one besides other using DOJO

Comment: Hi there! Add some code what you have tried so far. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to setup two different grids into two different Nodes.

Example:

```
<div id="emp1"> insert grid1</div>  <div id="emp2">insert grid2</div>
```

Make two diffrent stores for the Grids and startup both seperatly.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

```
<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="table1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="300px" field="Title">
                Title of Movie
            </th>
            <th width="50px">
                Year
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Producer
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" id="table2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="300px" field="Title">
                Title of Movie
            </th>
            <th width="50px">
                Year
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">
                Producer
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>


then using js, add store to initialize it.
var table1 = dijit.byId('table1');
var store1 = new ...whatEverStore;
table1.setStore(store1);

//do same for table2

Hope this helps
```